# Manjaro Linux not detecting wifi adapter?

Tags: wifi, manjaro, usb-device

So i just installed Manjaro KDE fresh, but it's not recognizing my wifi adapter. For the record I'm using a netgear a6210 adapter.

I type "ip link" in the terminal and it doesn't show up at all, though. Yet, it is listed if I type in "lsusb -v." Similarly if I type in "inxi -F" it does show up there as as well, though it's state is N/A, as well as its other attributes in the "inxi -F" output.

dmesg claims that it does see it. It outputs "New SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhxi_hcd" (I believe that last part is the kernel).

So it seems to only register that it's there but not do anything because it doesn't show up in "ip link". Thanks in advance for any help. I'll try to get the exact outputs if I can but I'm doing this from my phone, seeing as my computer isn't getting internet now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems this adapter (precisely, chipset  it is based on) is not supported in Linux kernel for now. Fortunately there is [driver](https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210) on GitHub (there is no package in AUR for it so you need to build it yourself).